# Is it possible to prevent Localstack from downloading the Gremlin server every time?

Tags: amazon-neptune, localstack

Each time I start localstack with testcontainers, when I create the Neptune server instance localstack is downloading and installing a Gremlin server to emulate Neptune. This slows down very much my integration tests. Can I avoid this? I can't find any info on this in the official documentation.

Comment: How are you starting localstack? Do you have a local bind mount into /var/lib/localstack? That is where localstack caches downloaded dependencies

Comment: @thrau I'm using localstack with testcontainers, using its defaults. It seems that it is downloading Neptune somewhere under my user home... I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. In general it's possible to configure Testcontainers and define a mount for `/var/lib/localstack` (which is what you would do when running LocalStack in standalone, see also https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/filesystem/#localstack-volume).

Testcontainers provide the function `withFileSystemBind` for that purpose.

Your code would look something like this:

```
 @Rule
 public LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer(localstackImage)
        .withExposedPorts(4510, 4511, 4512, 4513, 4514) // TODO the port can have any value between 4510-4559, but LS starts from 4510
        .withEnv("LOCALSTACK_API_KEY", api_key) // TODO add your API key here
        .withFileSystemBind("tmp-testcontainer", "/var/lib/localstack", BindMode.READ_WRITE);

 @Test
 public void testNeptune() {
        NeptuneClient neptune = NeptuneClient
                .builder()
                .endpointOverride(localstack.getEndpointOverride(LocalStackContainer.EnabledService.named("rds")))
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(
                        AwsBasicCredentials.create(localstack.getAccessKey(), localstack.getSecretKey())
                )).region(Region.of(localstack.getRegion())).build();

        software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptune.model.CreateDbClusterResponse response  = neptune.createDBCluster(software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptune.model.CreateDbClusterRequest.builder().engine("neptune").databaseName("hello").dbClusterIdentifier("testa").build());
        software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptune.model.DescribeDbClustersRequest request = software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptune.model.DescribeDbClustersRequest.builder().dbClusterIdentifier("testa").build();
        software.amazon.awssdk.services.neptune.model.DescribeDbClustersResponse describedb = neptune.describeDBClusters(request);

        // wait for db to be ready
        while(! describedb.dbClusters().get(0).status().equalsIgnoreCase("available")) {
            describedb = neptune.describeDBClusters(request);
        }
        assert describedb.dbClusters().get(0).status().equalsIgnoreCase("available");

    }
```

Using this bind-mount you will see a subfolder `lib` where the gremlin/tinkerpop server will be loaded. On re-run it will not be downloaded anymore because it's already there.

**But:**

- what I found is that TestContainers kills the container rather than stopping it (there is also [an open github issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1000))
- this prevents LocalStack of doing some proper cleanup before shutting down
- the `tmp` folder potentially has some left over data that will interfere with subsequent test runs.

So you would need to manually cleanup the `tmp` folder in the mounted directory (in my sample it's a subdirectory of `tmp-testcontainer`).

Hope that helps!